# Pyspark CI CD pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Has anybody built a CI CD pipeline for pyspark jobs? Is there any sample project that someone can share? Or any ideas on how to do that. We currently deploy all our code is AWS S3 and run spark-submit on EMR with --files, --pyfiles parameters. Is there a way to bundle everything together in to a zip file and deploy jobs? Or any better ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can share some of my experinece about using Jenkins to deploy pyspark to GCP Dataproc.
There are three step you need to handle：

1. Use Jenkins to trigger shell script create dataproc spark cluster (In you case is [emr-spark-submit-step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html))
2. Setup your python lib in spark cluster in two approach：

   2-1. Use custom image install conda with dependency lib.

   2-2. Archive your python dependency lib and upload to s3, and assign to --pyfiles
3. Use Jenkins submit you pyspark job

The following is sample script：

```
#!/bin/bash

MASTER="spark://<master ip>:7077"
NAME="sample-pyspark"

PY_FILE="jobs.zip"
CMD="main.py --job sampleTask \
     --job-args profile=gcp"


SPARK_SUBMIT=$(which spark-submit)

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/pvmax-ml/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/bin/python

SUBMIT_COMMAND="$SPARK_SUBMIT \
                --master $MASTER \
                --deploy-mode client \
                --driver-memory 4g \
                --executor-memory 4g \
                --executor-cores 2 \
                --conf spark.app.name=$NAME \
                --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
                --conf spark.network.timeout=120s \
                --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=7200 \
                --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=60 \
                --conf spark.rdd.compress=true \
                --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=8g \
                --conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=256 \
                --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" \
                --py-files $PY_FILE \
                $CMD
                "


echo "$SUBMIT_COMMAND"

eval "$SUBMIT_COMMAND"
```